# How to find the minimum element from two arrays in given time complexity in python

Tags: python, time-complexity, minimum

I have 2 arrays A and B. I'm trying to find the minimum from the elements which are common in the arrays A and B.

Like , if `A = [1,3,2,1]` & `B = [4,2,5,3,2]`, so it should return `2` because it is the minimum element which comes in both A & B. My code below works for this case, but for some cases it doesn't work. I don't know how to fix it. Please help!

```
def findMin(A, B):
    A.sort()
    B.sort()
    i = 0
    for x in A:
        if i < len(B) - 1 and B[i] < x:
            i += 1
        if x == B[i]:
            return x
    return -1
```

Also, I want the worst case time complexity to be `O((N+M)*log(N+M))`

Comment: What cases doesn't it work for?

Comment: It's unfair to ask a question, receive perfectly valid answers, then modify your question with an additional constraint that you should have stated in the first place. I've rolled back your question to its original state so it doesn't invalidate the existing answers and the time people have spent on doing so.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question was edited to add requirements that invalidated existing, good answers.

Answer (score 6):

You're throwing in sort there which you don't really need, find the intersection of the two using a set, then take the min...

```
>>> A = [1,3,2,1]
>>> B = [4,2,5,3,2]
>>> min(set(A).intersection(B))
2
```

Which would make your function:

```
def findMin(A, B, default=-1):
    return min(set(A).intersection(B), default=default)
```

The default argument is what gets returned if there's no intersection between the two lists (you appear to have chosen -1), but that's a Python 3.x addition, if you're stuck with Python 2.x, you need to potentially handle it via exceptions, eg:

```
def findMin(A, B, default=-1):
    try: 
        return min(set(A).intersection(B))
    except ValueError:
        return default
```

As to complexity, its worst case is `O(len(A) * len(B))` for the intersection, although the average case is `O(min(len(A), len(B))` (see [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity)), then the `min` operation you need to add on top is `O(N)`.

Comment: Does it work for all: N and M are integers within the range [1,..,10000] and each element of array A and B is an integer within the range [0, .., 1000,000,000]

Comment: @Ashka yes - try it out :)

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
b = [3,5,7,9]

shared = (set(a).intersection(b))

shared = sorted(shared)
print shared[0]
```

Returns `3`

Comment: Does it work for all: N and M are integers within the range [1,..,10000] and each element of array A and B is an integer within the range [0, .., 1000,000,000]

Comment: Is this a homework question by any chance? I don't know the numbers that you're going to be using. Just try it out with your worst case scenario numbers, i.e the highest numbers and see if it works.

Comment: Not a homework questions. Just trying out sample questions though. OK thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Itertools chain aproach:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> A = [1,3,2,1]
>>> B = [4,2,5,3,2]
>>> min(x for x in itertools.chain(A, B) if x in A and x in B)
2
```

Comment: Does it work for all: N and M are integers within the range [1,..,10000] and each element of array A and B is an integer within the range [0, .., 1000,000,000]

Comment: Using `in` on a list requires sequentially scanning the list so there's massive worst case scenarios here...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `set`s because it would be much faster due to its implementation. You just need to use `min` function over the intersection of two lists converted to `set`s. It's too easy, performant and doesn't require any sorting.

```
min(set(A) & set(B))
```

To get your initial algorithm working you just need to replace the first `if` by `while` loop:

```
while i < len(B) - 1 and B[i] < x:
```

Comment: Does it work for all: N and M are integers within the range [1,..,10000] and each element of array A and B is an integer within the range [0, .., 1000,000,000]

Answer (score 0):

In case there's a big difference in size of the arrays faster way is to create a `set` out of smaller one for the `intersection`:

```
def find(a, b):
    small, large = sorted([a, b], key=len)
    return min(set(small).intersection(large), default=-1)
```

Comparison with `100000` and `10000` elements:

```
import random
import timeit

def find_no_sort(a, b):
    return min(set(a).intersection(b), default=-1)

a = [random.randrange(0, 100000) for _ in range(100000)]
random.shuffle(a)
b = [random.randrange(0, 100000) for _ in range(10000)]
random.shuffle(b)

print('Sorted: ', timeit.timeit('find(a, b)', number=100, globals=globals()))
print('Not sorted: ', timeit.timeit('find_no_sort(a, b)', number=100, globals=globals()))
```

Output (Python 3.5.1 on Windows 8):

```
Sorted:  0.8935029393830678
Not sorted:  1.7727491360998975
```